# Can you charge a customer $20 by debit and give them a $20 bill instead of having a debit machine that can do cashback?

Tags: debit-card, cash, atm

If a customer wants cash to use our services but only has their debit card on them are you allowed to charge them $20 And give them a $20 bill back? Why do we specifically have to have a cash back system instead of doing that?

Comment: How much is your service?

Comment: Why not just pay for the service with the debit card?

Comment: When you say "charge them $20", do you mean "charge them an extra $20, above the price of the service"?

Comment: I don't see this as a PF question but a business question, which isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to answer your fundamental question: "Why do we specifically have to have a cash back system?"

It's because in general card providers want to be able to tell the difference between a purchase of an item and a cash advance to a customer. Credit card companies give benefits to people buying goods - reward points, interest free period etc. They can't do that with cash advances because it's open to abuse - you take your cash advance, claim the reward points, invest the cash until the interest free period runs out then use the same cash to pay off the card bill. Card providers enforce this by making businesses agree that they will not give out cash while claiming it is a payment for a service. (Incidentally it's the same reason why they insist that refunds for returns go back to the card the purchase was made on, to avoid the fiddle where you buy something, pay with a card and then immediately return it for cash).

Debit cards don't have the same issues, but debit cards and credit cards look very similar in the system. So you have a special system - cash back - that is allowed on some cards and not on others.

The answer to "Why can't the business do this?" is that the agreement with the card providers forbids it, for the above reasons.

Comment: consider that the business pays a proportional fee for the transaction. the provider might not even care if you want to pay for being an ATM for others.

Comment: I don't know if the card provider takes a percentage of cash back transactions or not, otherwise I would incorporate that into the answer.