# Refund to Different Payment Card in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, debit-card, payment, refund

I'm in the UK. I bought something *online* from Debenhams, and want to return it -- it is within the return period; no problems there. However, I no longer use the card that it was bought on.

> Is the retailer required to proved a refund to *some* card, or does it have to be the *original* payment card?

I'd like to just use my new debit card to get the refund, rather than an old one.
They'll surely offer me a gift card, but I don't want this.

The item is clothing, and I am returning due to the fact that it does not fit -- it is not faulty. It is in the window to return.

---

A short summary:

- purchased clothes online
- paid with card
- do not fit and want to return
- would like returned to a different (debit) card

---

PS Apologies if this is a duplicate. I had a look, but, somewhat surprisingly, couldn't find this information online (including SE)...

Comment: Does the returns policy of that retailer talk about credit cards?

Comment: It says that it will be credited to the original payment card. But I wonder whether this infringes on my rights? For example, I have had retailers tell me that they will not refund postage in some cases in contradiction to Consumer Rights Act. Just because a company says something, doesn't mean it's legally enforceable, if that makes sense? :)

Comment: As well as GS's excellent answer, another reason might be pressure from the card companies: from [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/126848/35567) – "_Incidentally it's the same reason why they [card companies] insist that refunds for returns go back to the card the purchase was made on, to avoid the fiddle where you buy something, pay with a card and then immediately return it for cash_".

Comment: @TripeHound Good point. Although this doesn't apply for debit--debit card replacement. Of course, one could buy on a _credit_ card, then return and ask for the money on a _debit_ card. I'm not sure if the merchant, at the time of return, would be able to tell if it was paid via credit or debit card...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a distance sale, you are entitled to rely on your statutory rights, namely the [Consumer Contracts Regulations](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2013/3134/made).

These explicitly state, in [s34](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2013/3134/regulation/34/made):

> (7) The trader must make the reimbursement using the same means of payment as the consumer used for the initial transaction, unless the consumer has expressly agreed otherwise.

So you don't have any right to insist on anything different.

Sometimes retailers choose to be more generous in their own contract terms, but from what you've said in comments, the returns policy of the retailer also refers to the original payment card.

If you were returning to a shop, then in practice they would probably ask for the card and it might just work out if you handed over a different one. But given that this was an online transaction, it's likely it'll all be processed automatically and you won't have any opportunity to persuade them to use a different one.

Comment: Ah, I had a look in the Consumer Contracts Regulations, but did not find this section which you have found! Thank you very much :)